# ExecuteScalar() sometimes returns empty but not null object. Why?

Tags: c#, executescalar

`ExecuteScalar()` sometimes returns empty object -not null- although the record is exists. When I analyze this object with quickwatch, I see that `object.GetType()` is equal to `DbNull`. 
I can handle this empty object but I need to know why it is returns empty object sometimes although the record is exists.

```
string sql = @"SELECT SentDate 
               FROM dbo.EmailOut                                    
               WHERE ID = @ID";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _cnn);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", ID));
object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (obj == null)
    return false
sentDate = (DateTime)obj;
cmd.Dispose();
```

Most of the time my query runs perfectly. Can you please check my code?

Comment: That "empty" object *is* null.

Comment: Records could be exist but maybe `SentDate` column is `null`?

Comment: hoping this is only an example, but you should wrap you `SqlCommand` in a `using` statement

Comment: Sentdate column is not null. I am sure. It is very strange

Comment: @SecretSquirrel: In general, yes. In this case, it's not terribly bad, since SqlCommand.Dispose is essentially a no-op. One should not get used to it, though, since, for example, not disposing an OleDbCommand or SqlCeCommand *will* cause trouble.

Comment: I have answered the reason under the Heinzi's answer. Please check it out

Answer (score 9):

A return value of `null` means that no record was found.

A return value of `DBNull` means that a record was found, but the value of `SentDate` in that record is `NULL`.

Comment: but sentdate is not null

Comment: @cihata87: That's... surprising. Are you sure about that? Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: @cihata87: Then we need to investigate further. Can you prepare a minimal sample (including the database data) that reliably reproduces the problem?

Comment: Finally I have found out that record is creating after 1 or 2 seconds later. But when I check sentdate is null because query runs so fast. So I did this System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); I always get the full object. Thank you